# HOW TO USE LOOP UNTIL DISCARD VALUE (FQTY) IS ZERO

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one medicine with 3 different batches as shown in below screenshot i.e total current stock is 3. i want to deduct the current stock by 1.3 without defining batch. so automatically it should deduct 1.3 from 3 (batchwise). for e.g it should go to 1st batch and deduct 1.3-1=0.3 then 0.3 should be minus from the second stock and so on. it should run in loop but my loop isn't working as i want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADMIN.labconsumption (
   fmedid       VARCHAR2,
   fqty         NUMBER,
   fsubdeptid   VARCHAR2
)
IS
   str      VARCHAR2 (5000);
   exist    NUMBER (1);
   exist1   NUMBER (1);
   rqdate   VARCHAR2 (20);
   dt       VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   SELECT ADMIN.wvf_inv_isexistsdmeddtlsstd1 (fmedid, fsubdeptid)
     INTO exist
     FROM DUAL;

   SELECT ADMIN.wvf_inv_isexistsdmeddtlsstd2 (fmedid, fsubdeptid)
     INTO exist1
     FROM DUAL;

   IF exist = 1 AND exist1 = 0
   THEN
      UPDATE inventory.dmeddtls
         SET currqty =
                  (SELECT currqty
                     FROM inventory.dmeddtls d
                    WHERE medid = fmedid
                      AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                      AND currqty > 0
                      AND ROWID =
                             (SELECT MAX (ROWID)
                                FROM inventory.dmeddtls e
                               WHERE medid = fmedid
                                 AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                                 AND e.medid = d.medid))
                - fqty
       WHERE medid = fmedid
         AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
         AND currqty != '0'
         AND currqty >= fqty;
   ELSE
      IF exist = 1 AND exist1 = 1
      THEN
        LOOP MERGE INTO INVENTORY.DMEDDTLS DTS USING (SELECT CURRQTY FROM (SELECT ROWID,CURRQTY
                     FROM inventory.dmeddtls d
                    WHERE medid = fmedid
                      AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                      AND currqty > 0 ORDER BY ROWID DESC) WHERE ROWNUM<2)
                      SRC 
                      ON (SRC.ROWID=DTS.ROWID)
                      WHEN MATCHED THEN
               UPDATE 
                  SET currqty =
                          SRC.CURRQTY  - fqty
                WHERE medid = fmedid
                  AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                  AND batchno =
                         (SELECT batchno
                            FROM inventory.dmeddtls d
                           WHERE medid = fmedid
                             AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                             AND currqty > 0
                             AND ROWID =
                                    (SELECT MAX (ROWID)
                                       FROM inventory.dmeddtls e
                                      WHERE medid = fmedid
                                        AND subdeptid = fsubdeptid
                                        AND e.medid = d.medid))
                  AND currqty > '0';
                EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
               END LOOP;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

[image]

this is my sample data discard quantity is 1.3. Now i want that loop first checks the 1st batch minus the value and goes to next one and so on. NOTE : I do not want to define the batch in query

Comment: Please, describe the rules using general words. It is not clear how you define processing orderm what "discard" is and how the result should be provided (stored somewhere/returned as a SQL result set/something different)

Comment: I have edited my question. Please help me out.